# how to get value from my foreign key in django form

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

Hi everyone I'm new there and I'm learning django right now. Sorry If my question isn't enough precisely but I don't really know how to call it. It's my code:

inventory/models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    #...
```

invoices/models.py

```
from inventory.models import Product

class Invoice(models.Model):
    #...

class Row(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    single_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    #...

class InventoryRow(Row):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

invoices/forms.py

```
class InvoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice

class InventoryRowForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InventoryRow
        fields = ('product')
```

invoices/view.py

```
def invoice(request):
    TableFormSet = formset_factory(InventoryRowForm, extra=6)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        invoice_form = InvoiceForm(request.POST)
        table_formset = TableFormSet(request.POST)

        if invoice_form.is_valid() and table_formset.is_valid():
            invoice = invoice_form.save(commit=False)
            #...
            invoice.save()

            for form in table_formset.forms:
                t = form.save(commit=False)
                print t.product.sale_price
                t.single_price = t.product.sale_price
                t.invoice = invoice
                #...
                t.save()
            #From this place code doesn't execute

            return redirect('invoices:index')
    else:
        invoice_form = InvoiceForm()
        table_formset = TableFormSet()

    context = {
        'invoice_form': invoice_form,
        'table_formset': table_formset,
    }
    context.update(csrf(request))

    return render(request, 'invoices/invoice.html', context)
```

When I fill and send my form, I've got HTTP error 500 with ExceptionType: DoesNotExist and ExceptionValue: InventoryRow has no product. Debug mode also highlights for me line with assignment "t.single_price = t.product.sale_price" What is surprise for me i can print value of t.product.sale_price to console and it is correct and my forms are saved. Does anyone know why that's happening?

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.0.104:8000/invoices/new/invoice

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap_toolkit',
 'bootstrapform',
 'inventory',
 'invoices')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/novirael/PythonEnvs/BMSEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/novirael/PythonEnvs/BMSEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/novirael/PythonEnvs/BMSEnv/bms/invoices/views.py" in invoice
  74.                 t.single_price = t.product.sale_price
File "/Users/novirael/PythonEnvs/BMSEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __get__
  324.                 "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name))

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /invoices/new/invoice
Exception Value: InventoryRow has no product.
```

Comment: which line throw the exception?

Comment: I added traceback above

Comment: single_price refers to the Row Model, where is the Row Form?

Comment: Row Model is parent class of InventoryRow which I use as InventoryRowForm. When I modify Row Model by adding product as ForeignKey, then InventoryRowForm by changing model to Row there is exactly the same problem as now.

Comment: Yes it's true and you're right. Thank you

Comment: Do some of the forms in your `table_formset` save okay?  If so, is it possible that you're just getting to the empty forms in your formset, and therefore they don't have any `product` associated?  If that might be the problem, wrap that line (`t.single_price = t.product.sale_price`) in a `try/except`, and a) if there's no exception, log a success message into the console, but b) if there is an exception, drop into a debbugger (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`), and inspect the form.  If *none* of the forms save properly, then this isn't the issue.

Comment: @novirael:  If my answer below is correct, please check the box to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just getting to the empty forms in your formset.

In your view:

```
TableFormSet = formset_factory(InventoryRowForm, extra=6)
```

Every time you hit this view, a formset with six extra *empty* forms will be created.  Then later in your `for` loop, the call to `form.save(commit=False)` will not return an `InventoryRow` with an associated `Product` object, hence the `DoesNotExist` error when you later try to access the `product.sale_price`.

You should add an `if` that checks that the form is "bound"[1]:

```
for form in table_formset.forms:
    if form.is_bound:
        t = form.save(commit=False)
        t.single_price = t.product.sale_price
        t.invoice = invoice
        #...
        t.save()
```

[1] More on "bound forms" here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms